# Not able to install Albert in linux mint19.2

Tags: linux-mint

```
sudo apt-get install albert
[sudo] password for aman:       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 albert : Depends: libpython3.5 (>= 3.5.0~b1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.2 Tina
Release:    19.2
Codename:   tina


apt-cache policy albert
albert:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.16.1
  Version table:
     0.16.1 500
        500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_16.04  Package
```

Answer (score 0):

This package is compiled for ancient ubuntu 16.04 (as you can recognize from the end of the repo URL), which (according to https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) shipped with python 3.5.1 — while your mint 16.2 is on python 3.6.7 and has no 3.5 version available.

So one way to install it would be to try to find a package that is built for ubuntu 18.10, which is on python 3.6.